# Remove string after second specific character occures from left

Tags: sql-server

I have this type of values in table column

```
154646@8@486
45465@6464@654
```

etc.

How can i remove everything after second @ character ? I need to display

```
154646@8
45465@6464
```

I can do it only for all @ but not for second

```
SELECT REPLACE(LEFT('45@Tra@lala', CHARINDEX('@','45@Tra@lala')-1),'_',' ')
```

returns **45** but not **45@Tra**

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the third parameter of `charindex()` that is used to specify where in the string the search will start.

```
declare @S varchar(20) = '45465@6464@654';
select left(@S, charindex('@', @S, charindex('@', @S)+1)-1);
```

Result

```
45465@6464
```